# How to rotate YOLO bounding boxes in 90° steps?

Tags: python, math, yolo

I have a dataset of images for a computer vision object detection project. I am using the YOLO framework, which stores the object labels (bounding boxes) for the training data in text files, one per image, that have the following format:

- one row per object
- each row is in `class x_center y_center width height` format
- box coordinates and dimensions must be normalized format, from 0.0 - 1.0
- class numbers are zero-indexed

Now I want to create more training images by rotating the images I have in 90° steps. Doing so for the images themselves is easy, but I also need to create new text files with the annotations, which reflect these rotations. Thus the label coordinates in the new text files need to be rotated versions of the original annotations. Using Python, how can I calculate these 90° rotations for the object annotations (i.e. for 90, 180, and 270 degrees)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up with rotating by 90 degrees for three with this function:

```py
def rotate_yolo_labels_90(yolo_labels_path, img_width, img_height):
    with open(yolo_labels_path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    rotated_lines = []

    for line in lines:
        class_idx, x_center_norm, y_center_norm, width_norm, height_norm = map(float, line.split())
        class_idx = int(class_idx)

        # Convert normalized center coordinates to pixel coordinates
        x_center = x_center_norm * img_width
        y_center = y_center_norm * img_height

        # Compute new pixel coordinates for rotated bounding box
        x_new = y_center
        y_new = img_width - x_center
        width_new = height_norm * img_height
        height_new = width_norm * img_width

        # Convert new pixel coordinates back to normalized coordinates
        x_new_norm = x_new / img_height
        y_new_norm = y_new / img_width
        width_new_norm = width_new / img_height
        height_new_norm = height_new / img_width

        # Append rotated annotation to list of strings
        rotated_line = f"{class_idx} {x_new_norm:.6f} {y_new_norm:.6f} {width_new_norm:.6f} {height_new_norm:.6f}\n"
        rotated_lines.append(rotated_line)

    return rotated_lines
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks for sharing your code. I slightly changed your code. You multiply and divide the width and height by the same numbers in here:

```
width_new = height_norm * img_height
height_new = width_norm * img_width
width_new_norm = width_new / img_height
height_new_norm = height_new / img_width
```

**New Code:**

```
def rotate_yolo_labels_90(yolo_labels_path, img_width, img_height):
    with open(yolo_labels_path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    rotated_lines = []

    for line in lines:
        class_idx, x_center_norm, y_center_norm, width_norm, height_norm = map(float, line.split())
        class_idx = int(class_idx)

        # Convert normalized center coordinates to pixel coordinates
        x_center = x_center_norm * img_width
        y_center = y_center_norm * img_height

        # Compute new pixel coordinates for rotated bounding box
        x_new = y_center
        y_new = img_width - x_center

        # Convert new pixel coordinates back to normalized coordinates
        x_new_norm = x_new / img_height
        y_new_norm = y_new / img_width

        # NEW ADDED
        width_new_norm = height_norm
        height_new_norm = width_norm

        # Append rotated annotation to list of strings
        rotated_line = f"{class_idx} {x_new_norm:.6f} {y_new_norm:.6f} {width_new_norm:.6f} {height_new_norm:.6f}\n"
        rotated_lines.append(rotated_line)

    return rotated_lines
```